# what would be the approaches to handle real time rule based events generated by iot devices?

Tags: alert, monitoring, iot, sensors

I am working on iot project in which i need to send alerts to users based on rules which already defined by user like if Temperature value matches certain condition then send alerts to users and their are multiple conditions.
I achieved to send the alerts to users when condition matches by using following
steps

```
1)store threshold values,condition of a device in mysql.
2)when the device data comes to server i checked the current value with given condition with threshold value and send the alert.
3)And also their are multiple conditions associated with devices so i need to check each and every condition.
```

So what i need is like,is their any technology that i can use in my project.

Comment: **How** does the data "come to the server"? Why can't you add monitoring there at ingestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can consider to use [Azure IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/about-iot-hub) and [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/).
You can store threshold values and condition of a device in Azure Database for MySQL or other MySQL host.

Azure IoT Hub supports communications both from the device to the cloud and from the cloud to the device. We can use Azure IoT Hub to monitor the [telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-dotnet) data. Azure Function can process the data from Azure IoT Hub. An [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/functions-js-iot-hub-processing/) here shows how to capture data from your devices or sensors, perform aggregation, filtering or some other custom processing on this data, and store it on a database. It is a typical tutorial for your scenario.

I am not sure if it is a better solution for you, hope that helpful.

Comment: This sounds biased towards Azure :/

Comment: Yes, it is an optional solution.